# malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Since iOS 14 my iOS app prints this error message to the console (As the first message).

`AppName(5088,0x1064438c0) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.`

I couldn't find any other similar issues when searching on Google and I don't have any idea what's causing this. I'm running on an iPhone XS Max, iOS 14.0.1, Swift 5.

Comment: Same. No clue what might be the cause...

Comment: Same. iOS 14.4 Xcode 12.5 beta 3

Comment: Same Error message on Apple M1, Monterey, Xcode 13.1 (13A1030d). To duplicate, make a new Project, using Game template. Run it. Log reports about ten sanitizerBug -related bugs. Seems to hobble the thread sanitizer (but I'm just learning thread sanitizer).

Comment: this link maybe usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861144/get-an-error-as-a-out40780-0x1130af600-malloc-nano-zone-abandoned-due-to-in

Answer (score 36):

After digging into Apple's libmalloc source code, I found the offending function `nano_malloc`. You can view the code at Apple's open source site [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libmalloc/libmalloc-140.40.1/src/nano_malloc.c.auto.html).

As you can see from the code, `nano_malloc` call `nano_preallocate_band_vm`  to pre-allocate a certain amount of heap memory (for optimization purpose, I guess). If the kernel does not return an address at exactly `NANOZONE_SIGNATURE` (0x6 << 44), `nano_preallocate_band_vm` report failure ==> `nano_init` print out the message.

Unlike Linux community, Apple does not comment on their internal implementations, so I do not have any authoritative answer. But here is my hypothesis:

1. Libmalloc preallocate memory for optimization purpose only ==> Failed to do so does not affect the result of any program.
2. Address/Thread sanitizers allocate their data structures before libmalloc does ==> libmalloc can not acquire a memory chunk at the exact address as it expect ==> failed to pre-allocate.

Regardless, as the source code shows, Apple give you 2 ways to turn off this warnings:

1. Undef `NANO_PREALLOCATE_BAND_VM` (only viable if you compile libmalloc from source)
2. Set the environment variable `MallocNanoZone` to 0.

I did try the 2nd option and success.

FYI, It's not Xcode or Swift's specific problem. I compiled C/C++ code with Address Sanitizer `clang -fsanitize=address -o main main.c`, the program emit exactly the same warning and the same solution worked.

My tools' version for future reference:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.0.1
BuildVersion:   21A559
```

Comment: All the code if your .zprofile is empty `touch ~/.zprofile`, `open ~/.zprofile`, `export MallocNanoZone='0'`

Answer (score 3):

## Turn off Thread Sanitizer in Scheme

I noticed this error would appear and disappear with the project Scheme's Diagnostic option under Runtime Sanitization: **Thread Sanitizer**
[image: Uncheck Thread Sanitizer]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to: set active scheme (next to the play and stop button) -> edit scheme -> diagnostics, then turn on "Thread Sanitizer." With Thread Sanitizer on, the error will be caught and you will receive a warning that is more descriptive in the debugger. If the description is a Swift access race, then you should use a Thread Safe Barrier in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this (noticed that Thread Sanitizer only works for the Simulator also) and I don't get any Threading issues as they did in this video, that's how Thread Sanitizer works right? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ds7CGc_kjE

Comment: Yes it should point out any threading issues... however, in my experience I have had the Thread Sanitizer not point out any issues when I should have been running into issues while reading and writing data to the same datasource while using a concurrent queue... But best of luck! If it is a threading issue these unfortunately can be pretty difficult to debug :(

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you built your code but in my case, all I did is add a `do try catch` in my code.
Something from this:

```
static func fetchAlbumWithAsyncURLSession() async throws -> [Album] {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=album") else {
        throw AlbumsFetcherError.invalidURL
    }
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    let iTunesResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ITunesResult.self, from: data)
    return iTunesResult.results
}
```

To something like this:

```
static func fetchAlbumWithAsyncURLSession() async throws -> [Album] {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=album") else {
        throw AlbumsFetcherError.invalidURL
    }
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let iTunesResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ITunesResult.self, from: data)
        return iTunesResult.results
    } catch {
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

And then I got the error :D

Best regards!

Comment: It is from Swift 5.5 

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had too much going on in the main thread. I pushed a heavy task to the back of the queue and the warning went away.

Before

```
.onAppear() {
    player.play()
}
```

After

```
.onAppear() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        player.play()
    }
}
```