# C++ Clang AddressSanitizer unable to getting work on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, memory-leaks, clang

I'm trying to experiment with Apple Clang's AddressSanitizer but I'm facing very wired issues. I'm currently using Clang 13.0.1 on both mac and godbolt.

Let me explain.

On [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zdx6ch74c), compiling with the `-fsanitize=address` flag, the following snippet produces a memory leak, as expected

```cpp
int main() {
    auto *p = new int; // leak
    return 0;
}
```

and godbolt returns

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x4f9078 in operator new(unsigned long) /root/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:95
    #1 0x4fc878 in main /app/example.cpp:4:15
    #2 0x7f9fda7b70b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x240b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 4 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

This is perfectly identical to gcc behaviour.

Then, deleting the dangling pointer, the AddressSanitizer won't complain anymore

```cpp
int main() {
    auto *p = new int;
    delete p; // no leak
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's the link.](https://godbolt.org/z/31Yxf47ra)

So far, so good. Problems start when compiling on a real Mac with `clang++`.
Compiling the first example with `-fsanitizer=address` (or any other piece of code), it simply returns the following message:

```
main(8227,0x118347600) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.
```

and no leaks are detected.

Surfing around the web, I found that Apple's version of clang has also the flag `-fsanitize=leak`, but that option, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55778432/6882933), is not available on the clang version provided by Xcode, so I tried to install clang 13 via brew.

Then I tried to compile a completely empty `main` function

```cpp
int main() {}
```

with the `-fsanitize=leak` and it produces a ton of leaks:

```
main(8321,0x111169600) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.

=================================================================
==8321==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1888 byte(s) in 59 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x10f830b7d in wrap_calloc+0x5d (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x8b7d)
    #1 0x7ff81452d84f in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x88 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x884f)
    #2 0x7ff81452bb3f in map_images_nolock+0x161b (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6b3f)
    #3 0x7ff81452a4bb in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x54bb)
    #4 0x1110f82ca in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x112 (dyld:x86_64+0xf2ca)
    #5 0x1110f3798 in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x28 (dyld:x86_64+0xa798)
    #6 0x1110f81b1 in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x51 (dyld:x86_64+0xf1b1)
    #7 0x11110ba84 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_notify_register(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x4e (dyld:x86_64+0x22a84)
    #8 0x7ff81452a329 in _objc_init+0x51a (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x5329)
    #9 0x7ff8144e0992 in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x2992)
    #10 0x7ff8144ee1b7 in libdispatch_init+0x136 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x101b7)
    #11 0x7ff81f476897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897)
    #12 0x1110fddda in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xb5 (dyld:x86_64+0x14dda)
    #13 0x111124256 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3b256)
    #14 0x11111b859 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0x32859)
    #15 0x1110eadb2 in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x80 (dyld:x86_64+0x1db2)
    #16 0x11111b5ea in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0xb2 (dyld:x86_64+0x325ea)
    #17 0x111123dad in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0x1d1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3adad)
    #18 0x1110fdd0d in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x8f (dyld:x86_64+0x14d0d)
    #19 0x111104229 in dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x1d (dyld:x86_64+0x1b229)
    #20 0x111111495 in dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()+0x25 (dyld:x86_64+0x28495)
    #21 0x1110ef37c in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xd72 (dyld:x86_64+0x637c)
    #22 0x1110ee4d3 in start+0x183 (dyld:x86_64+0x54d3)

Direct leak of 1888 byte(s) in 59 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x10f830b7d in wrap_calloc+0x5d (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x8b7d)
    #1 0x7ff81452d84f in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x88 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x884f)
    #2 0x7ff81452d91b in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x154 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x891b)
    #3 0x7ff81452bb3f in map_images_nolock+0x161b (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6b3f)
    #4 0x7ff81452a4bb in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x54bb)
    #5 0x1110f82ca in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x112 (dyld:x86_64+0xf2ca)
    #6 0x1110f3798 in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x28 (dyld:x86_64+0xa798)
    #7 0x1110f81b1 in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x51 (dyld:x86_64+0xf1b1)
    #8 0x11110ba84 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_notify_register(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x4e (dyld:x86_64+0x22a84)
    #9 0x7ff81452a329 in _objc_init+0x51a (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x5329)
    #10 0x7ff8144e0992 in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x2992)
    #11 0x7ff8144ee1b7 in libdispatch_init+0x136 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x101b7)
    #12 0x7ff81f476897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897)
    #13 0x1110fddda in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xb5 (dyld:x86_64+0x14dda)
    #14 0x111124256 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3b256)
    #15 0x11111b859 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0x32859)
    #16 0x1110eadb2 in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x80 (dyld:x86_64+0x1db2)
    #17 0x11111b5ea in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0xb2 (dyld:x86_64+0x325ea)
    #18 0x111123dad in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0x1d1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3adad)
    #19 0x1110fdd0d in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x8f (dyld:x86_64+0x14d0d)
    #20 0x111104229 in dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x1d (dyld:x86_64+0x1b229)
    #21 0x111111495 in dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()+0x25 (dyld:x86_64+0x28495)
    #22 0x1110ef37c in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xd72 (dyld:x86_64+0x637c)
    #23 0x1110ee4d3 in start+0x183 (dyld:x86_64+0x54d3)

Direct leak of 160 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x10f830b7d in wrap_calloc+0x5d (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x8b7d)
    #1 0x7ff81452d84f in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x88 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x884f)
    #2 0x7ff81452d91b in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x154 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x891b)
    #3 0x7ff81452d8f8 in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x131 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x88f8)
    #4 0x7ff81452bb3f in map_images_nolock+0x161b (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6b3f)
    #5 0x7ff81452a4bb in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x54bb)
    #6 0x1110f82ca in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x112 (dyld:x86_64+0xf2ca)
    #7 0x1110f3798 in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x28 (dyld:x86_64+0xa798)
    #8 0x1110f81b1 in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x51 (dyld:x86_64+0xf1b1)
    #9 0x11110ba84 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_notify_register(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x4e (dyld:x86_64+0x22a84)
    #10 0x7ff81452a329 in _objc_init+0x51a (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x5329)
    #11 0x7ff8144e0992 in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x2992)
    #12 0x7ff8144ee1b7 in libdispatch_init+0x136 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x101b7)
    #13 0x7ff81f476897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897)
    #14 0x1110fddda in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xb5 (dyld:x86_64+0x14dda)
    #15 0x111124256 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3b256)
    #16 0x11111b859 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0x32859)
    #17 0x1110eadb2 in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x80 (dyld:x86_64+0x1db2)
    #18 0x11111b5ea in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0xb2 (dyld:x86_64+0x325ea)
    #19 0x111123dad in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0x1d1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3adad)
    #20 0x1110fdd0d in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x8f (dyld:x86_64+0x14d0d)
    #21 0x111104229 in dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x1d (dyld:x86_64+0x1b229)
    #22 0x111111495 in dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()+0x25 (dyld:x86_64+0x28495)
    #23 0x1110ef37c in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xd72 (dyld:x86_64+0x637c)
    #24 0x1110ee4d3 in start+0x183 (dyld:x86_64+0x54d3)

Direct leak of 160 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x10f830b7d in wrap_calloc+0x5d (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x8b7d)
    #1 0x7ff81452d84f in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x88 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x884f)
    #2 0x7ff81452d8f8 in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x131 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x88f8)
    #3 0x7ff81452bb3f in map_images_nolock+0x161b (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6b3f)
    #4 0x7ff81452a4bb in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x54bb)
    #5 0x1110f82ca in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x112 (dyld:x86_64+0xf2ca)
    #6 0x1110f3798 in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x28 (dyld:x86_64+0xa798)
    #7 0x1110f81b1 in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x51 (dyld:x86_64+0xf1b1)
    #8 0x11110ba84 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_notify_register(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x4e (dyld:x86_64+0x22a84)
    #9 0x7ff81452a329 in _objc_init+0x51a (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x5329)
    #10 0x7ff8144e0992 in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x2992)
    #11 0x7ff8144ee1b7 in libdispatch_init+0x136 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x101b7)
    #12 0x7ff81f476897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897)
    #13 0x1110fddda in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xb5 (dyld:x86_64+0x14dda)
    #14 0x111124256 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3b256)
    #15 0x11111b859 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0x32859)
    #16 0x1110eadb2 in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x80 (dyld:x86_64+0x1db2)
    #17 0x11111b5ea in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0xb2 (dyld:x86_64+0x325ea)
    #18 0x111123dad in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0x1d1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3adad)
    #19 0x1110fdd0d in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x8f (dyld:x86_64+0x14d0d)
    #20 0x111104229 in dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x1d (dyld:x86_64+0x1b229)
    #21 0x111111495 in dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()+0x25 (dyld:x86_64+0x28495)
    #22 0x1110ef37c in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xd72 (dyld:x86_64+0x637c)
    #23 0x1110ee4d3 in start+0x183 (dyld:x86_64+0x54d3)

Direct leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x10f830b7d in wrap_calloc+0x5d (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x8b7d)
    #1 0x7ff81452d84f in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x88 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x884f)
    #2 0x7ff81452d91b in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x154 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x891b)
    #3 0x7ff81452d8f8 in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x131 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x88f8)
    #4 0x7ff81452d8f8 in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x131 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x88f8)
    #5 0x7ff81452bb3f in map_images_nolock+0x161b (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6b3f)
    #6 0x7ff81452a4bb in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x54bb)
    #7 0x1110f82ca in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x112 (dyld:x86_64+0xf2ca)
    #8 0x1110f3798 in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x28 (dyld:x86_64+0xa798)
    #9 0x1110f81b1 in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x51 (dyld:x86_64+0xf1b1)
    #10 0x11110ba84 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_notify_register(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x4e (dyld:x86_64+0x22a84)
    #11 0x7ff81452a329 in _objc_init+0x51a (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x5329)
    #12 0x7ff8144e0992 in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x2992)
    #13 0x7ff8144ee1b7 in libdispatch_init+0x136 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x101b7)
    #14 0x7ff81f476897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897)
    #15 0x1110fddda in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xb5 (dyld:x86_64+0x14dda)
    #16 0x111124256 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3b256)
    #17 0x11111b859 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0x32859)
    #18 0x1110eadb2 in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x80 (dyld:x86_64+0x1db2)
    #19 0x11111b5ea in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0xb2 (dyld:x86_64+0x325ea)
    #20 0x111123dad in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0x1d1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3adad)
    #21 0x1110fdd0d in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x8f (dyld:x86_64+0x14d0d)
    #22 0x111104229 in dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x1d (dyld:x86_64+0x1b229)
    #23 0x111111495 in dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()+0x25 (dyld:x86_64+0x28495)
    #24 0x1110ef37c in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xd72 (dyld:x86_64+0x637c)
    #25 0x1110ee4d3 in start+0x183 (dyld:x86_64+0x54d3)

Direct leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x10f830b7d in wrap_calloc+0x5d (libclang_rt.lsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x8b7d)
    #1 0x7ff81452d84f in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x88 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x884f)
    #2 0x7ff81452d8f8 in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x131 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x88f8)
    #3 0x7ff81452d8f8 in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x131 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x88f8)
    #4 0x7ff81452bb3f in map_images_nolock+0x161b (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6b3f)
    #5 0x7ff81452a4bb in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x54bb)
    #6 0x1110f82ca in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x112 (dyld:x86_64+0xf2ca)
    #7 0x1110f3798 in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x28 (dyld:x86_64+0xa798)
    #8 0x1110f81b1 in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x51 (dyld:x86_64+0xf1b1)
    #9 0x11110ba84 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_notify_register(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))+0x4e (dyld:x86_64+0x22a84)
    #10 0x7ff81452a329 in _objc_init+0x51a (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x5329)
    #11 0x7ff8144e0992 in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x2992)
    #12 0x7ff8144ee1b7 in libdispatch_init+0x136 (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x101b7)
    #13 0x7ff81f476897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897)
    #14 0x1110fddda in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xb5 (dyld:x86_64+0x14dda)
    #15 0x111124256 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3b256)
    #16 0x11111b859 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0x32859)
    #17 0x1110eadb2 in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x80 (dyld:x86_64+0x1db2)
    #18 0x11111b5ea in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0xb2 (dyld:x86_64+0x325ea)
    #19 0x111123dad in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0x1d1 (dyld:x86_64+0x3adad)
    #20 0x1110fdd0d in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x8f (dyld:x86_64+0x14d0d)
    #21 0x111104229 in dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0x1d (dyld:x86_64+0x1b229)
    #22 0x111111495 in dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain()+0x25 (dyld:x86_64+0x28495)
    #23 0x1110ef37c in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xd72 (dyld:x86_64+0x637c)
    #24 0x1110ee4d3 in start+0x183 (dyld:x86_64+0x54d3)

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 4160 byte(s) leaked in 130 allocation(s).
```

The godbolt and mac clang versions are exactly the same. Nevertheless, I'm aware that the godbolt version is for gnu/linux and it is not compiling on a real mac. Thus, is it something related to the OS kernel?

How can I get the "regular" behaviour of the AddressSanitizer, aka: how can I simply have a working sanitizer on a mac?

Comment: A quick Google for the malloc error message turned up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64126942/malloc-nano-zone-abandoned-due-to-inability-to-preallocate-reserved-vm-space

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks,  I already saw that, but the question was not about that specific issue, but rather than why I cannot get the address sanitizer working as expected, ad moreover why I'm getting a ton of leaks on an empty program

Comment: About the duplicate question: actually the linked answers do not solve my issues

Comment: Agreed, the linked answers do not solve the issue. Instead, until this question is reopened, let me write the answer in this comment: 1. Create a file `lsan.supp` with the contents `leak:realizeClassWithoutSwift`, then 2. run your app (with ASAN enabled) with the following environment variable: `LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=lsan.supp`. This will suppress the false positives (see "realizeClassWithoutSwift(...)" in OP's question).